# Why do members of a template class need to be parameterized by the parameters of their template class

Tags: c++, templates

In page 668 of Stroustrup's book (4th edition - first printing) you`ll find the following example of a template class?

```
template<typename C>
class String{
public:
    String();
    ...
private:
    int sz;
    C* ptr;
};
```

In page 679 the author writes:

> Members of a template class are themselves templates parameterized by
>   the parameters of their template class. When such a member is defined
>   outside its class, it must explicitly be declared as template. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> template<typename C>
> String<C>::String()
>     :sz(0), ptr(ch)
> {
>     ch[0] = {}; 
> }
> ```

There is an obvious error in this example. The variable `ch`  doesn't make any sense above. But that has nothing to do with my question. What I'd like to know is why the constructor above can't be defined without the parameter `C`, as shown below?

```
template<typename C>
String::String()
    : sz(0), ptr(nullptr)
{
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`String` is the name of a template, not a class. A template is not not even a type, so it doesn't have members. A template specialization is a class, however. You need to plug in `C` in order to specify which specialization it is you are referring to for the purposes of this definition.

Now it just so happens that the definition itself is a template, but that is because you are defining things for a family of specializations. Nevertheless the fact remains that you need to name those specializations explicitly.

Finally, the reason you only need to specify the specialization once is that the template name is treated in a special manner inside the scope of a class template specialization. Inside that scope the template name refers to the the injected class name, to the specialization itself. That's why

```
template<typename C>
String<C>::String<C>()
    :sz(0), ptr(ch)
{
}
```

... can be written as...

```
template<typename C>
String<C>::String()
    :sz(0), ptr(ch)
{
}
```

Since `String<C>` already established the specialization we are referring to, and we are inside its scope, we can use `String` with its special meaning as the injected class name.

Comment: Where in the standard does it say that a member of a template class is a specialization when defined outside of its template class?

Comment: @WaldB - [\[temp.class\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.class#3).

Comment: @WaldB - Oh, I think I misunderstood you. It's not that *"a template class is a specialization when defined outside"*. It's just that in general, when you write `my_temp<C>`, you *are referring* to a specialization. Any specialization can be, and is, referred to by its *template-id* ([\[temp.names\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.names#1))

Comment: [\[temp.spec\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.spec#3) says that "An explicit specialization declaration is introduced by `template <>`. I don't see any `template <>`in the snippets shown in my question and in your answer. Could you clarify?

Comment: @WaldB - Apologies. It's what I get for having too many tabs open. Right paragraph number, but wrong section.  https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.class#3

Comment: @WaldB - Wait. My original link is correct. How did you get there?

Comment: In your second link [\[temp.names\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.names#1) there is a link for the term [template specialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.spec).

Comment: @WaldB - Yes. And paragraph 4 speaks of specializations being implicitly instantiated as well. The term is overloaded, and has several uses. It is common to refer by "specialization" to any class which is from a template. Even if it wasn't created by the act of specializing. That's what names/1 is doing.

Answer (score 0):

C++ could have been designed with a special rule to make this trivial and common case work like you expect it to. The current rules are more consistent though, as they still work the in more complex cases.

In particular, consider the following :

```
template<typename C, int I> class String { };
template<typename C> class String<C,0> { String(); };
template<typename C> class String<C,1> { String(); };
```

This is a class template with two **partial** specializations.

Now the first ctor is defined as

```
template<typename C> String<C,0> :: String() { }
```

You see that the template argument list has one extra argument, `,0` which indicates the specific specialization. Partial specializations vary some, but not all template parameters of the base template. You have to specify which parameters can vary, and which have fixed values.